# Is there a way to schedule jobs to specific processor in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, job-scheduling

I am a new user of Apache Flink and I am currently aiming at testing out a scheduling algorithm on a heterogeneous processing system. Hence, which processor I am deploying each job to becomes quite important. However, I could not find how I can specify the processor ID that I am deploying my jobs to, nor could I find a way to make the processors return the availability of them.
I sincerely appreciate your help if you could kindly give me some hints of how I can do these. Hope that you enjoy your day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed throgh a similar problem to schedule and monitor the flink subtasks to specific cpu cores of the machines. I use `LinuxJNAAffinity` to my problem (https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) . Maybe you can base your solution on mine. Here is one of my UDFs.

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.sense.flink.pojo.Point;
import org.sense.flink.pojo.ValenciaItem;
import org.sense.flink.util.CRSCoordinateTransformer;
import org.sense.flink.util.CpuGauge;
import org.sense.flink.util.SimpleGeographicalPolygons;

import net.openhft.affinity.impl.LinuxJNAAffinity;

public class ValenciaItemDistrictMap extends RichMapFunction<ValenciaItem, ValenciaItem> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 624354384779615610L;
    private SimpleGeographicalPolygons sgp;
    private transient CpuGauge cpuGauge;
    private BitSet affinity;
    private boolean pinningPolicy;

    public ValenciaItemDistrictMap() {
        this(false);
    }

    public ValenciaItemDistrictMap(boolean pinningPolicy) {
        this.pinningPolicy = pinningPolicy;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        this.sgp = new SimpleGeographicalPolygons();
        this.cpuGauge = new CpuGauge();
        getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().gauge("cpu", cpuGauge);

        if (this.pinningPolicy) {
            // listing the cpu cores available
            int nbits = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            // pinning operator' thread to a specific cpu core
            this.affinity = new BitSet(nbits);
            affinity.set(((int) Thread.currentThread().getId() % nbits));
            LinuxJNAAffinity.INSTANCE.setAffinity(affinity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ValenciaItem map(ValenciaItem value) throws Exception {
        // updates the CPU core current in use
        this.cpuGauge.updateValue(LinuxJNAAffinity.INSTANCE.getCpu());
        System.err.println(ValenciaItemDistrictMap.class.getSimpleName() + " thread[" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + "] core[" + this.cpuGauge.getValue() + "]");

        List<Point> coordinates = value.getCoordinates();
        boolean flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (flag) {
            Tuple3<Long, Long, String> adminLevel = sgp.getAdminLevel(coordinates.get(i));
            if (adminLevel.f0 != null && adminLevel.f1 != null) {
                value.setId(adminLevel.f0);
                value.setAdminLevel(adminLevel.f1);
                value.setDistrict(adminLevel.f2);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            // if we did not find a district with the given coordinate we assume the
            // district 16
            value.clearCoordinates();
            value.addCoordinates(
                    new Point(724328.279007, 4374887.874634, CRSCoordinateTransformer.DEFAULT_CRS_EPSG_25830));
            value.setId(16L);
            value.setAdminLevel(9L);
            value.setDistrict("Benicalap");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks so much Felipe for your help:)

Comment: Nice. Please consider to up vote my answer or even voto as a solution for you.